# How to know when a browser peer is disconnected in aiortc?

Tags: python, webrtc, aiortc

```
from aiortc import RTCPeerConnection

pc = RTCPeerConnection()
print(pc.connectionState)
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Χρήστος\Desktop>python 123.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "123.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(pc.connectionState)
AttributeError: 'RTCPeerConnection' object has no attribute 'connectionState'
```

It's the first property in the [documentation of aiortc](https://aiortc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) but i cannot retrieved it.

Note: I also tried with `connectionstatechange` event but either that worked.

**Edit:** That's the methods the `pc` object has:

```
['_RTCPeerConnection__assertNotClosed', '_RTCPeerConnection__assertTrackHasNoSender', '_RTCPeerConnection__connect', '_RTCPeerConnection__createDtlsTransport', '_RTCPeerConnection__createSctpTransport', '_RTCPeerConnection__createTransceiver', '_RTCPeerConnection__gather', '_RTCPeerConnection__getTransceiverByMLineIndex', '_RTCPeerConnection__getTransceiverByMid', '_RTCPeerConnection__localDescription', '_RTCPeerConnection__localRtp', '_RTCPeerConnection__remoteDescription', '_RTCPeerConnection__remoteRtp', '_RTCPeerConnection__setSignalingState', '_RTCPeerConnection__updateIceConnectionState', '_RTCPeerConnection__updateIceGatheringState', '_RTCPeerConnection__validate_description', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_add_event_handler', '_call_handlers', '_emit_handle_potential_error', '_emit_run', 'addIceCandidate', 'addTrack', 'addTransceiver', 'close', 'createAnswer', 'createDataChannel', 'createOffer', 'emit', 'getReceivers', 'getSenders', 'getStats', 'getTransceivers', 'listeners', 'on', 'once', 'remove_all_listeners', 'remove_listener', 'setLocalDescription', 'setRemoteDescription']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aiortc` uses `pyee` for making `aiortc` event-driven and as you can see in the official GitHub example ([webcam/webcam.py](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/main/examples/webcam/webcam.py)), you must put an event listener on an event named `iceconnectionstatechange`.

Checkout the code snippet below:

```py
from aiortc import RTCPeerConnection


pc = RTCPeerConnection()


@pc.on("iceconnectionstatechange")
async def on_iceconnectionstatechange():
    print(f"ICE connection state is {pc.iceConnectionState}")

    if pc.iceConnectionState == "failed":
        # Do something
```

In your question you mentioned that you've tried `connectionstatechange` event but it's actually `iceconnectionstatechange` and that's why it didn't work the first time.

Comment: Ok now i have another error: when pc is closed from browser `frame = await track.recv()` fails (only 1 time)

Comment: I added inside a `try` to hide the Exception. But anyway there is a timeout that `on_iceconnectionstatechange` is called. How can i decrease it?

Comment: Checkout the example github page I mentioned above and review the code, I've been working with `aiortc` for 2 or 3 month now, and here's my advice: Don't rush and read all the examples!
The `webcam` example is good enough for start.